# Beginner Thread or Dispatcher direction

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, webclient

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  I want to make a simple WPF application that has a button and a textbox.  I click the button, and it starts to loop downloading a bunch of files.  I can't seem to figure out how to not let the downloading stop the UI from updating.  From what I can gather I'm probably going to have to use some threading code; but so far all the examples I've found and tried don't work for me.  Any help or direction on where I should look and learn would be great.  I can't seem to figure out how I can output those textbox.text messages around each file download.

```
foreach (var ticker in tickers)
    {
        var url = string.Format(urlPrototype, ticker, startMonth, startDay, startYear, finishMonth, finishDay, finishYear, "d");
        var csvfile = directory + "\\" + ticker.ToUpper() + ".csv";

        tbOutput.Text += "Starting Download of : " + ticker + "\n";

        webClient.DownloadFile(url, csvfile);

        tbOutput.Text += "End Download of : " + ticker + "\n";
        numStocks++;
    }
    tbOutput.Text += "Total stocks downloaded = " + numStocks + "\n";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mark your method as *async*, you can use the `DownloadFileTaskAsync` method

```
await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, csvfile)
```

Comment: @ErnieCooper If one of the answers helped you, you may think to *accept* it.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot ways to implement it. For example:

1) Using async/await if you programming in .Net Framework 4.5. It is simpler than BackgroundWorker

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri someUrl=new Uri(@"http://dotnetperls.com");
    WebClient webClient=new WebClient();
    await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(someUrl, csvFile);
}
```

2) BackgroundWorker. This class is really intended to make asynchronous operations to avoid freezing UI.
See http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/multi-threading-with-the-backgroundworker

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker bw;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWok;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }              
}


void bw_RunWorkerComleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventAgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The result is " + e.Result.ToString());
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var ticker in tickers)
    {
        var url = string.Format(urlPrototype, ticker, startMonth, startDay, startYear, finishMonth, finishDay, finishYear, "d");
        var csvfile = directory + "\\" + ticker.ToUpper() + ".csv";
        webClient.DownloadFile(url, csvfile);    
        numStocks++;
     }
    e.Result = "End Of Download ";
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    tbOutput.Text += "Starting Download of : " + ticker + "\n";
}
```

3) Use Thread class and update using Dispatcher class:

```
ThreadStart job = new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    foreach (var ticker in tickers)
    {
       var url = string.Format(urlPrototype, ticker, startMonth, startDay, startYear, finishMonth, finishDay, finishYear, "d");
       var csvfile = directory + "\\" + ticker.ToUpper() + ".csv";
       webClient.DownloadFile(url, csvfile);    
       numStocks++;
    }
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=> tbOutput.Text += "End Download of : " + ticker + "\n";}));

});

Thread thread = new Thread(job);
thread.Start();
```

http://www.beingdeveloper.com/use-dispatcher-in-wpf-to-build-responsive-applications

Comment: Try adding some samples instead of just linking - links are fragile. They're great for additional information, but your answer should stand just fine on its own if the links ever stop working.

Comment: thanks for the examples.  I used webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync from an above reply and that worked, but in the long term I'll likely want to do multithreading so I can get a progress bar going, and hopefully download multiple things at the same time (or crunch at the same time) thanks!

Comment: @ErnieCooper, it might be more useful for searchers to see Eser's answer marked as an answer and this is some point of praise:).

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), it allows you to output those messages into the TextBox around each file download. Here is a crude example adapted for your requirement.

1) At the class level, create an instance of the BackgroundWorker class and add event handlers to the BackgroundWorker instance's events:

```
BackgroundWorker workerDownload = new BackgroundWorker();
workerDownload.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
workerDownload.DoWork += workerDownload_DoWork;
workerDownload.ProgressChanged += workerDownload_ProgressChanged;
workerDownload.RunWorkerCompleted += workerDownload_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

2) Create an event handler for the background worker's DoWork event:

> The DoWork event handler is where you run the time-consuming operation
>   on the background thread. Any values that are passed to the background
>   operation are passed in the Argument property of the DoWorkEventArgs
>   object that is passed to the event handler.

```
private void workerDownload_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var ticker in tickers)
    {
        // you can pass the required info as argument:
        string[] arrArg = (string[])e.Argument;
        string theUrl = arrArg[0];
        string directory = arrArg[1];

        var url = string.Format(theUrl, ticker);
        var csvfile = directory + "\\" + ticker.ToUpper() + ".csv";

        // perform the download operation and report progress:
        workerDownload.ReportProgress(0, "Starting Download of : " + ticker + "\n");
        webClient.DownloadFile(url, csvfile);
        workerDownload.ReportProgress(100, "End Download of : " + ticker + "\n");
        numStocks++;
    }
}
```

3) Create an event handler for the background worker's ProgressChanged event:

> In the ProgressChanged event handler, add code to indicate the
>   progress, such as updating the user interface.

```
private void workerDownload_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tbOutput.Text += e.UserState.ToString();
}
```

4) Create an event handler for the RunWorkerCompleted event:

> The RunWorkerCompleted event is raised when the background worker has
>   completed.

```
private void workerDownload_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    tbOutput.Text += "Total stocks downloaded = " + numStocks + "\n";
}
```

5) Start running the background operation by calling the RunWorkerAsync method:

```
int numStocks = 0;
string strDirectory = "<a_directory>";
string strUrl = string.Format(urlPrototype, startMonth, startDay, startYear, finishMonth, finishDay, finishYear, "d");
string[] args = new string[2] { strUrl, strDirectory };
workerDownload.RunWorkerAsync(args);
```